# Alternative approach of Setting optionCriteria

Tags: java, smartgwt

I am working on Java and SmartGWT and is trying to set criteria into the field which has some innate fetch operation id in it. When I check the logger for the line of `logger.info("id: " + criteria .getAttribute("id"))`, I can see that there is value for the id. However, when it comes to `field.setOptionCriteria(criteria );`, it seems that the criteria is not set to the field FormItem object. May I know what would be the correct approach of handling this ?

```
 private static void setCriteria(FormItem field, String id) {
    
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            criteria.addCriteria("id", id);
            try {
                logger.info("id: " + criteria.getAttribute("id"));
            }catch(Exception exception){};
            field.setOptionCriteria(criteria );
        }
```